# Trying to implement Header, main and footer React JS

Tags: css, reactjs, header, footer

I am starting out React JS today so I wanted to implement Something like a Header, main body and footer
So i have done few things but the footer does not display the way its expected to , just the Header.

My code is looking like this :

for the Css

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
  }

.header{
    background-color: #007FC0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 25px 0;
}

.container{
    flex : 1 1 auto;
    color:white;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #16192C;
}
```

For the code I have this :

```
import React from 'react';
import './app-styles.css'

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <header className="header">
        </header>


        <footer className="footer">
        </footer>

    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

It just shows the header and nothing else. Any assistance. What exactly am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put some height to the footer? As of now, it looks more of CSS issue than React

Comment: @NikhilGoyal, thanks. Apparently height was the enemy. Thank you again